# php var_dump in xdebug style without using xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

On productive environments, xdebug is usually not available. Is there a replacement for the better readable xdebug's var_dump() display, e.g. a php library?

Comment: 1) http://codeaid.net/php/improved-var_dump()-with-colored-output

2) https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/10/smart-alternative-phps-var_dump-function/

Google can do magic! ;)

Answer (score 0):

`var_export()` does a much cleaner output and also has the advantage of being valid PHP code should you want to import it.